# FBSDK messenger on iOS

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

I have been searching for a while about how to import FBMessengerSDK to my own iOS App, but couldn't find any

I have tried to search for the documentation or tutorials on how to integrate the FBSDK. The documentations do not help much

```
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios#message
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger/ios/#back_to_messenger
```

What I want to achieve is that I could enable the user open the messenger from my app after pressed a particular menu in my app, and will auto redirect the user to a particular person (like a customer support) inside the Messenger App. It has been so frustrating in integrating FBSDK to my app.

Can somebody help me please? Or maybe there is another documentation link elsewhere?

Comment: Did you tried fb pods? `pod 'FacebookCore` `pod 'FacebookLogin`

Comment: Hi jamil, the problem is I couldnt find any tutorial on how to integrate the fbmessenger SDK, do you know any?

Comment: Google.
`https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger/ios/`

Comment: Jamil, i already post that link inside my question